# Establishing the existence of a strictly increasing real function, discontinuous at all rationals and continuous at all irrationals

Tags: real-analysis

> **Goal:** Show that there exists a *strictly increasing* function on $\mathbb{R}$ discontinuous at all points of $\mathbb{Q}$ and continuous at all irrational numbers.

**Attempt:**

1. Let $f(x)$ denote the popcorn function on $\mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{q} &\text{if }x\text{ is rational, }x=\tfrac{p}{q}\text{ in lowest terms and } q > 0\\
  0           &\text{if }x\text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$

The **popcorn function** $f(x)$ can be visualized on $(0,1)$ as follows:

[image]

2. Let $g(x): \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the following function:

$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  0 &\text{if }x=0\\
  \sup\{g(y) : y < x\} + \frac{1}{q} &\text{if }x>0\text{ is rational, }x=\tfrac{p}{q}\text{ in lowest terms and } q > 0\\
  \sup\{g(y) : y < x\}           &\text{if }x>0\text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$

3. Extend $g(x)$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by making $g(-x) = -g(x)$.  We'll refer to this extended function as $g(x)$ as well (abusing the name $g$ without harm).
4. **$g$ is strictly increasing:** Let $x < y$.  Then there exists a fully reduced rational $p/q \in (x,y)$ so that

$$
g(x) < g(x) + p/q \le g\left(p/q\right) \le g(y)
$$

which implies $g(x) < g(y)$ as desired.

5. **$g$ is discontinuous at all points of $\mathbb{Q}$:**  Let $x = {p \over q}$ be a fully reduced rational.  We can further assume $x$ is positive without loss of generality.  Let $\epsilon = {1 \over q}$.  Then for any $\delta > 0$, we have that $(x- \delta, x)$ contains at least one rational $y$ so that

$$
g(y) < g(y) + {1 \over q} \le g(x)
$$

This in particular implies that $g(y) \notin (g(x)- \epsilon, g(x)+\epsilon)$ so that $g$ fails to be continuous at $x$ as desired.

**Question:** How can I show that $g$ is **continuous** at all irrational points?

Comment: You mean to use $\sup f(x)$ in the definition of $g(x)$?

Comment: I meant to use $\sup g(x)$ so that the function can be  strictly increasing.

Comment: Then the definitin of $g$ is circular. In fact from $1>\frac12>\frac13>\ldots$, you would require $g(1)\ge 1+g(\frac12)\ge 1+\frac12+g(\frac13)\ge 1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion: Try 
$$ g(x)=\sum_{0\le q\le x}f(q)^3$$
or
$$ g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n^3}$$
for $x>0$ and then
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{if }x=0\\-g(-x)&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: How does one establish that $\sum_{0\le q\le x}f(q)^3$ is continuous on irrational points?  I'm assuming this is where the power of $3$ will come in handy.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen Can you help [Connection of complex $e^z$ and real Dirichlet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867643/) please?