# Complex exponential function vs Real Dirichlet (popcorn)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 3.51

### Firstly, proof verification on the values of $e^{b \ln a}$:

> ([Exer 3.51](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9F8M.png)) [Part I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521041): Prove $e^{b \ln(a)}$ is single valued $\iff b \in \mathbb Z$. Part II: What if $b \in \mathbb Q$?

I tried:

> **Part I** ($b \in \mathbb Z$)

Pf:

By definition of $a^b$:

$$a^b:=e^{bLn(a)} = e^{b(\ln|a|+iArg(a))} = e^{b\ln|a|}e^{ibArg(a)}$$

By definition of $e^{b\ln(a)}$, $\exists k \in \mathbb Z$ s.t.

$$e^{b\ln(a)} = e^{b(\ln|a|+i\arg(a))} = e^{b\ln|a|}e^{ibArg(a)}e^{2kbi\pi} =: a^be^{2kbi\pi}$$

$\therefore, e^{b\ln(a)}$ is single valued $\iff e^{b\ln(a)} = a^b \iff 1 = e^{2kbi\pi}$

Now $$1 = e^{2kbi\pi} = \cos(2kbi\pi) + i\sin(2kbi\pi) \iff$$

$$\cos(2kbi\pi) = 1 \wedge \sin(2kbi\pi) = 0 \iff bk \in \mathbb Z \iff b \in \mathbb Z$$

$\therefore, e^{b\ln(a)}$ is single valued $\iff e^{b\ln(a)} = a^b \iff b \in \mathbb Z$

QED

> **Question 1**. Where have I gone wrong for Part I, if anywhere?

-

> **Part II**  ($b \in \mathbb Q$)

Let $b:=\frac pq$, where $p,q$ are coprime positive integers (For any negative, $\cos$ is even and $\sin$ is odd). Now consider $\cos$:

$$\cos(2kbi\pi) := \cos(2k \frac pq i\pi)$$

whose value is different depending where $p$ is in $\{\overline{0},\overline{1}, \dots, \overline{q-1}\}$

$\therefore, e^{b\ln(a)}$ has $q$-values because $p$ has $q$-values $\mod \ q$.

> **Question 2**. Where have I gone wrong for Part II, if anywhere?

---

### Now that that's over with:

---

> **Question 3**. (Something I noticed on my own in re Exer 3.51 but not asked in Exer 3.51)
>
> What's the connection to the popcorn function aka [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) aka modified Dirichlet $\frac1q 1_{x=\frac pq}$?

In Part II of Exer 3.51, $q$ is extracted from $\frac pq$.

In the popcorn function from elementary real analysis, $\frac1q$ is extracted from $\frac pq$. It seems the popcorn function is computing number of solutions $q$ to a complex equation and then inverting the computation $\frac 1 q$.

---

> **Question 4**. (Also something I noticed on my own in re Exer 3.51 but not asked in Exer 3.51)
>
> What exactly is the connection to solving the roots of unity?

The roots of unity are the solutions of $z^n=1$, which turn out to be $z=e^{2k\pi\frac{m}{n}}$ whose value is different depending where $m$ is in $\{\overline{0},\overline{1}, \dots, \overline{n-1}\}$. This looks similar to Part II.

Comment: Please mark places from the book

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov What do you mean by 'mark places' please?

Comment: To understand the question, I need firstly to understand the logic of the author of the book. For this, I need to see which part of the text is a quote from the book and which one is not.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Ok I added back the link to the text for Exer 3.51. That's about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality,
$$\ln b=\operatorname{Log} b+2n\pi i$$ where the principal logarithm is taken and $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Then,
$$e^{a\ln b}=e^{a\operatorname{Log} b}\cdot e^{2an\pi i}$$

The first part is obviously single-valued, so let’s discuss the single-valued-ness of the second part.

**When $a\in\mathbb Z$:**

$$an\in\mathbb Z\implies \cos(2an\pi)=1, \sin(2an\pi)=0 \implies e^{2an\pi i}=1\,\,\forall n$$ Thus the expression in single-valued.

**When $a\not\in\mathbb Z$:**

We will show that $e^{2an\pi i}- e^{2a(n+1)\pi i}\ne0$.

Considering real part:
$$\cos(2an\pi)-\cos(2a(n+1)\pi=-2\sin(a\pi(2n+1))\sin(-2a\pi)$$

Since $(2n+1)a, -2a\not\in\mathbb Z$, the difference of two cosines is non-zero.

This shows that a change of choice of $n$ would result in the change of value of the expression, thus the expression is multi-valued.

In conclusion the *iff* statement is proved.

Comment: Thanks Szeto, but (1) where exactly did I go wrong, if anywhere? (2) What's the connection to the popcorn function? (3) What is the relationship of proving this result and solving for the roots of unity?

Comment: @BCLC Sorry, but what is popcorn function?

Comment: Szeto, no need to be [sorry](https://www.boredpanda.com/stop-saying-sorry-say-thank-you-comic-yao-xiao/): Thomae's function, named after Carl Johannes Thomae, has many names: the popcorn function, the raindrop function, the countable cloud function, the modified Dirichlet function, the ruler function, the Riemann function, or the Stars over Babylon (John Horton Conway's name).

Comment: @BCLC Thanks! Actually, why/where do you think you go wrong?

Comment: Szeto, just checking. Nowhere is an answer :p Do you have any answers for 2,3 or 4? I edited question to hopefully further clarify.